# Regular expression to validate an email in perl

Tags: perl

I am new in Perl and trying to catch hold of the scripting language where I come across regular expression to validate a email address. I am sharing the perl script. I am not sure where I am making mistake in it. The \@ part is omitted always following which the correct email id is also showing as invalid.

Here is the code :

```
#!/usrs/bin/perl/
$string = "XYZ@yahoo.com";
if ( $string =~ /([a-zA-Z]+)\@([a-zA-Z]+)\.(com|net|org)/)
{
    print "TRUE";
    print $string;
}
else
{
    print "FALSE";
    print $string;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: There are digits in my email...

Comment: I am new in regular expression also. But I have tried here with only character class like from only [a-zA-Z]. You can add there [a-zA-Z0-9] if you have alphanumeric one as Arijit suggested below. But in my case it seems \@ and after the \@ characters are skipped until \.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The regex for validating an email address is included in the [source code for Email::Valid](https://metacpan.org/source/RJBS/Email-Valid-1.200/lib/Email/Valid.pm). I've copied it below:

```
$RFC822PAT = <<'EOF';
[\040\t]*(?:\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:(?:\\[^\x80-\xff]|\([^\\\x80-\
xff\n\015()]*(?:\\[^\x80-\xff][^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\))[^\\\x80-\xf
f\n\015()]*)*\)[\040\t]*)*(?:(?:[^(\040)<>@,;:".\\\[\]\000-\037\x80-\x
ff]+(?![^(\040)<>@,;:".\\\[\]\000-\037\x80-\xff])|"[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015
"]*(?:\\[^\x80-\xff][^\\\x80-\xff\n\015"]*)*")[\040\t]*(?:\([^\\\x80-\
xff\n\015()]*(?:(?:\\[^\x80-\xff]|\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:\\[^\x80
-\xff][^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\))[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\)[\040\t]*
)*(?:\.[\040\t]*(?:\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:(?:\\[^\x80-\xff]|\([^\
\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:\\[^\x80-\xff][^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\))[^\\\
x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\)[\040\t]*)*(?:[^(\040)<>@,;:".\\\[\]\000-\037\x8
0-\xff]+(?![^(\040)<>@,;:".\\\[\]\000-\037\x80-\xff])|"[^\\\x80-\xff\n
\015"]*(?:\\[^\x80-\xff][^\\\x80-\xff\n\015"]*)*")[\040\t]*(?:\([^\\\x
80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:(?:\\[^\x80-\xff]|\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:\\[^
\x80-\xff][^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\))[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\)[\040
\t]*)*)*@[\040\t]*(?:\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:(?:\\[^\x80-\xff]|\([
^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:\\[^\x80-\xff][^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\))[^\
\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\)[\040\t]*)*(?:[^(\040)<>@,;:".\\\[\]\000-\037\
x80-\xff]+(?![^(\040)<>@,;:".\\\[\]\000-\037\x80-\xff])|\[(?:[^\\\x80-
\xff\n\015\[\]]|\\[^\x80-\xff])*\])[\040\t]*(?:\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()
]*(?:(?:\\[^\x80-\xff]|\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:\\[^\x80-\xff][^\\\
x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\))[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\)[\040\t]*)*(?:\.[\04
0\t]*(?:\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:(?:\\[^\x80-\xff]|\([^\\\x80-\xff\
n\015()]*(?:\\[^\x80-\xff][^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\))[^\\\x80-\xff\n\
015()]*)*\)[\040\t]*)*(?:[^(\040)<>@,;:".\\\[\]\000-\037\x80-\xff]+(?!
[^(\040)<>@,;:".\\\[\]\000-\037\x80-\xff])|\[(?:[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015\[\
]]|\\[^\x80-\xff])*\])[\040\t]*(?:\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:(?:\\[^\
x80-\xff]|\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:\\[^\x80-\xff][^\\\x80-\xff\n\01
5()]*)*\))[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\)[\040\t]*)*)*|(?:[^(\040)<>@,;:".
\\\[\]\000-\037\x80-\xff]+(?![^(\040)<>@,;:".\\\[\]\000-\037\x80-\xff]
)|"[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015"]*(?:\\[^\x80-\xff][^\\\x80-\xff\n\015"]*)*")[^
()<>@,;:".\\\[\]\x80-\xff\000-\010\012-\037]*(?:(?:\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\0
15()]*(?:(?:\\[^\x80-\xff]|\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:\\[^\x80-\xff][
^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\))[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\)|"[^\\\x80-\xff\
n\015"]*(?:\\[^\x80-\xff][^\\\x80-\xff\n\015"]*)*")[^()<>@,;:".\\\[\]\
x80-\xff\000-\010\012-\037]*)*<[\040\t]*(?:\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?
:(?:\\[^\x80-\xff]|\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:\\[^\x80-\xff][^\\\x80-
\xff\n\015()]*)*\))[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\)[\040\t]*)*(?:@[\040\t]*
(?:\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:(?:\\[^\x80-\xff]|\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015
()]*(?:\\[^\x80-\xff][^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\))[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()
]*)*\)[\040\t]*)*(?:[^(\040)<>@,;:".\\\[\]\000-\037\x80-\xff]+(?![^(\0
40)<>@,;:".\\\[\]\000-\037\x80-\xff])|\[(?:[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015\[\]]|\\
[^\x80-\xff])*\])[\040\t]*(?:\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:(?:\\[^\x80-\
xff]|\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:\\[^\x80-\xff][^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*
)*\))[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\)[\040\t]*)*(?:\.[\040\t]*(?:\([^\\\x80
-\xff\n\015()]*(?:(?:\\[^\x80-\xff]|\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:\\[^\x
80-\xff][^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\))[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\)[\040\t
]*)*(?:[^(\040)<>@,;:".\\\[\]\000-\037\x80-\xff]+(?![^(\040)<>@,;:".\\
\[\]\000-\037\x80-\xff])|\[(?:[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015\[\]]|\\[^\x80-\xff])
*\])[\040\t]*(?:\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:(?:\\[^\x80-\xff]|\([^\\\x
80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:\\[^\x80-\xff][^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\))[^\\\x80
-\xff\n\015()]*)*\)[\040\t]*)*)*(?:,[\040\t]*(?:\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015(
)]*(?:(?:\\[^\x80-\xff]|\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:\\[^\x80-\xff][^\\
\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\))[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\)[\040\t]*)*@[\040\t
]*(?:\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:(?:\\[^\x80-\xff]|\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\0
15()]*(?:\\[^\x80-\xff][^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\))[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015
()]*)*\)[\040\t]*)*(?:[^(\040)<>@,;:".\\\[\]\000-\037\x80-\xff]+(?![^(
\040)<>@,;:".\\\[\]\000-\037\x80-\xff])|\[(?:[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015\[\]]|
\\[^\x80-\xff])*\])[\040\t]*(?:\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:(?:\\[^\x80
-\xff]|\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:\\[^\x80-\xff][^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()
]*)*\))[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\)[\040\t]*)*(?:\.[\040\t]*(?:\([^\\\x
80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:(?:\\[^\x80-\xff]|\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:\\[^
\x80-\xff][^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\))[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\)[\040
\t]*)*(?:[^(\040)<>@,;:".\\\[\]\000-\037\x80-\xff]+(?![^(\040)<>@,;:".
\\\[\]\000-\037\x80-\xff])|\[(?:[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015\[\]]|\\[^\x80-\xff
])*\])[\040\t]*(?:\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:(?:\\[^\x80-\xff]|\([^\\
\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:\\[^\x80-\xff][^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\))[^\\\x
80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\)[\040\t]*)*)*)*:[\040\t]*(?:\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015
()]*(?:(?:\\[^\x80-\xff]|\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:\\[^\x80-\xff][^\
\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\))[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\)[\040\t]*)*)?(?:[^
(\040)<>@,;:".\\\[\]\000-\037\x80-\xff]+(?![^(\040)<>@,;:".\\\[\]\000-
\037\x80-\xff])|"[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015"]*(?:\\[^\x80-\xff][^\\\x80-\xff\
n\015"]*)*")[\040\t]*(?:\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:(?:\\[^\x80-\xff]|
\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:\\[^\x80-\xff][^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\))
[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\)[\040\t]*)*(?:\.[\040\t]*(?:\([^\\\x80-\xff
\n\015()]*(?:(?:\\[^\x80-\xff]|\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:\\[^\x80-\x
ff][^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\))[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\)[\040\t]*)*(
?:[^(\040)<>@,;:".\\\[\]\000-\037\x80-\xff]+(?![^(\040)<>@,;:".\\\[\]\
000-\037\x80-\xff])|"[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015"]*(?:\\[^\x80-\xff][^\\\x80-\
xff\n\015"]*)*")[\040\t]*(?:\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:(?:\\[^\x80-\x
ff]|\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:\\[^\x80-\xff][^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)
*\))[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\)[\040\t]*)*)*@[\040\t]*(?:\([^\\\x80-\x
ff\n\015()]*(?:(?:\\[^\x80-\xff]|\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:\\[^\x80-
\xff][^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\))[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\)[\040\t]*)
*(?:[^(\040)<>@,;:".\\\[\]\000-\037\x80-\xff]+(?![^(\040)<>@,;:".\\\[\
]\000-\037\x80-\xff])|\[(?:[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015\[\]]|\\[^\x80-\xff])*\]
)[\040\t]*(?:\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:(?:\\[^\x80-\xff]|\([^\\\x80-
\xff\n\015()]*(?:\\[^\x80-\xff][^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\))[^\\\x80-\x
ff\n\015()]*)*\)[\040\t]*)*(?:\.[\040\t]*(?:\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(
?:(?:\\[^\x80-\xff]|\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:\\[^\x80-\xff][^\\\x80
-\xff\n\015()]*)*\))[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\)[\040\t]*)*(?:[^(\040)<
>@,;:".\\\[\]\000-\037\x80-\xff]+(?![^(\040)<>@,;:".\\\[\]\000-\037\x8
0-\xff])|\[(?:[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015\[\]]|\\[^\x80-\xff])*\])[\040\t]*(?:
\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*(?:(?:\\[^\x80-\xff]|\([^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]
*(?:\\[^\x80-\xff][^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)*\))[^\\\x80-\xff\n\015()]*)
*\)[\040\t]*)*)*>)
EOF
```

But your actual problem is this line:

```
$string = "XYZ@yahoo.com";
```

The `@yahoo` looks like an array variable to Perl, and and you don't have an array called `@yahoo` it gets replaced with an empty string. Try printing the value of `$string` to see what you get.

The solution is either to use single quotes (so the array variable isn't expanded):

```
$string = 'XYZ@yahoo.com';
```

Or to escape the `@` with a `\`:

```
$string = "XYZ\@yahoo.com";
```

Alway add `use strict` and `use warnings` to your Perl programs. They would have told you what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for you got the code and pasted it over here. But it is really big and sorry to say that I am not understanding a bit also.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Definitely I will add 'use strict' and 'use warnings' in my perl code now onwards ..Its working ...

Comment: You're not supposed to understand the regex. It's there to scare people into using the module which hides the regex from you :-)

Answer (score 8):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Email::Valid;

my $email_address = 'a.n@example.com';

unless( Email::Valid->address($email_address) ) {
    print "Sorry, that email address is not valid!";
}
```

Reference Site: http://learn.perl.org/examples/email_valid.html

For Regex Pattern try this:

```
 my $pattern= '^([a-zA-Z][\w\_\.]{6,15})\@([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4})$';
```

Reference Site: https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/8652/Email-validation-using-Regular-Expression-in-Perl.html

Comment: Thanks .. it is working but I needed with regular expression

Comment: That's a really bad regex to use. Valid email addresses can use far more characters than that. Domain names can have more than two sections (for example, I own the domain dave.org.uk). Also many newer top-level domains (for example .london) are longer than four characters.

Comment: @Dave Cross: Your inputs are valuable. Thanks.

Comment: my $pattern= '^([a-zA-Z][\w\_\.]{2,})\@([a-zA-Z0-9.-]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4})$'; 

My email didn't work until I changed the username part to 2 characters or more. Many emails have user names smaller than 6 characters and some larger than 15.

Comment: Based on the OP's question we have answered. And there is a default module is available to find basic email domain formats.

Answer (score 1):

Change your if condition to

```
  if ($string =~ /^[a-z0-9A-Z][A-Za-z0-9.]+[A-Za-z0-9]\@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+$/)
```

and change 
`$string = "XYZ@yahoo.com";` to

```
$string = 'XYZ@yahoo.com';
```

Refference : http://perlmaven.com/email-validation-using-regular-expression-in-perl
 for details.

Comment: I have tried and made the script as you suggested : Here is the modified script.                                                                                                              #!/users/bin/perl/
$string = "XYZ@yahoo.com";

if ($string =~ /^[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9.]+[a-z0-9])?\@[a-z0-9.-]+$/)
{
 print "TRUE";
 print $string;
}
else
{
 print "FALSE";
 print $string;
} but the output is "FALSE"

Comment: I am using Strawberry Perl. It is showing me same "FALSE" even with your updated regular expression.

Comment: Please change **$string = "XYZ@yahoo.com";** to **$string = 'XYZ@yahoo.com';** . it considering @yahoo as a array variable.

Comment: Thanks ... it is working now. I wonder if a string in perl can only be in single quote or I can use the double quote also. Here it puzzles me a little.

Comment: Always `use strict;` and `use warnings`, that would have given you an error saying that `@yahoo` was not declared.

Comment: You can put strings in double quotes in Perl. But anything that looks like a variable will be expanded. `@yahoo` looks like a variable, so it gets expanded (to an empty string as the array doesn't exist) in double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if ($email =~ /^[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9.]+[a-z0-9])?\@[a-z0-9.-]+$/)
```

And some test code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $email = "john.doe\@acme.org";

if ($email =~ /^[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9.]+[a-z0-9])?\@[a-z0-9.-]+$/) {
    print "Valid email\n";
} else {
    print "Not valid email\n";
}

exit;
```

Output:

```
Valid email
```

Comment: The problem is not the regex. The problem is the assignment to `$string`.

Comment: yes I understood .. I wonder if a string in perl can only be in single quote or I can use the double quote also. Here it puzzles me a little.                                Thanks ...

Comment: I have explained that in another comment elsewhere on this page and also in my answer. Perl accepts strings in double quotes, but it expands variables in double-quoted strings. And `@yahoo` looks like a (non-existent) variable. If you don't understand that, can I recommend that you find the time to read a good introductory Perl tutorial.

Comment: I do not know why this of my question is still getting downvote even today whereas I can see this was asked 1 year ago. so surprised.