# Regex to filter email address in Urls

Tags: regex, perl, akamai

I need to filter out any spam requests in our url that has email address or any sort of personal information.

For example : if anyone enters the url

> www.mydomain.com/en-us?email=abc@gmail.com

it should redirect to

> www.mydomain.com/en-us?email=

[Use regex to pattern match the email and remove that] 
basically it should keep the url as is and remove emailaddress

**another example**

Redirect

> www.mydomain.com/en-us/sompePage/SomeStructure?query=abc.gmail.com

to

> www.mydomain.com/en-us/sompePage/SomeStructure?query=

This is what I tried :

`(http|https)://mydomain.com/(^((?!\.)[\w-_.]*[^.])(@\w+)(\.\w+(\.\w+)?[^.\W])$`
 but throws an error
*Back story and reasoning, if interested*

We looked at google analytics and realized that our website is getting with a random email address with a random query string. But Google is marking them as storing personal information and hence see it as a violation of policy. Sl we are trying to place some regex in akamai so that these requests never hit the server. 
(We also have a fallback javascript in place to handle the same)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Looking more closely, I forgot we had added the Match with Regular Expressions. Our RegEx engine defaults to PCRE syntax, so you could theoretically make a comprehensive Match in the whole query string:
[image: match on regular expression]

Double check and test on the Staging platform before you commit. And double check the RegEx. I took that from [emailregex.com](https://emailregex.com) and didn't test it myself.

**ORIGINAL:**

With Akamai, the Property Manager tool lets you do this with a new rule. You should check the documentation and test before deploying, or consult with your account team for more specific questions.

In the rule, you'll want to add a match for the query string like so:
[image: property manager with new rule and match]

From there, add the behavior to have the Akamai platform do what you want. If it's a simple redirect, then you can use the Redirect behavior and remove the query strings completely. Something like this:
[image: redirect behavior]

As the info box says, this specific use case might be better handled with the Redirector Cloudlet. But there are many things you can do once you've matched on that query string.

Answer (score 0):

Your examples are not very good at explanation of the problem. The main issue is how to identify 'mail' which you would like to remove.

I would take other approach:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $debug = 0;

my %url;

while( <DATA> ) {
    print if $debug;

    chomp;

    m|(https{0,1})://([\w\d\.]+)/(.*)\?(.*)|;

    @url{qw(proto dn path query)} = ($1,$2,$3,$4);

    print Dumper(\%url) if $debug;

    # now do whatever your heart desire with $url{query}

    $url{query} =~ /(.*=)/;
    $url{query} = $1;

    print Dumper(\%url) if $debug;

    printf "%s://%s/%s/%s\n",
                $url{proto},    # protocol
                $url{dn},       # domain name
                $url{path},     # directory path
                $url{query};    # query

}

__DATA__
http://www.example.org/en-us?email=abc@gmail.com
https://www.example.org/en-us/sompePage/SomeStructure?query=abc.gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I have read your question once more and realized that probably akamai allows only regex modification and do not includes full fledged perl scripts.

Then probably what you looking for will be `s|=.*|=|` or `s/=.*/=/`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while( <DATA> ) {
    s|=.*|=|;
    print;
}

__DATA__
www.mydomain.com/en-us?email=abc@gmail.com
www.mydomain.com/en-us/sompePage/SomeStructure?query=abc.gmail.com
```

But again this method does not identify **e-mail** in query. Your question is not complete to make full judgement on the problem.

You could try `s/[\w\d\.\-]+@[\w\d\.]+//` as **e-mail** matching substitute regex.

Comment: not sure what the confusion is. All i want is to strip the email id from url.  the rest of the url remails same. I am trying to find the regex that would find the email in url

Comment: Will you have any other parameters in query? What do you plan to do with them? See above `s/[\w\d\.\-]@[\w\d\.\*]//` it should strip e-mail address if there is no other parameters provided. Otherwise you need to provide some '_stop_' after e-mail and probably this '_stop_' will be **&** symbol (you need to see how it encoded in query). For example `abc.gmail.com` does not _match_ e-mail address (e-mail should look like **user@domain** where user can include _letters/digits/./-_ and domain _letters/digits/./-_).

Comment: Please check following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37703864/regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-in-perl) about verification of e-mail address. Particulary you should refer to [RFC822 Section 6.1](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/#z8) for email address 'specification'. Sorry, in previous reply please read `s/[\w\d\.\-]+@[\w\d\.]+//`

Answer (score -1):

The code for [Email::Valid](https://metacpan.org/release/Email-Valid/source/lib/Email/Valid.pm) contains a [regex for validating an email address](https://metacpan.org/release/Email-Valid/source/lib/Email/Valid.pm#L402). It's rather more complex than most people think though :-)